# passing cookies in http request from classic asp page

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, httprequest, httpresponse

I have an interesting scenario that I need assistance with.

I have a classic asp page. The function of this page is to perform a http request to an external url and process the response from it.

Eg page.asp makes a http request to page2.aspx

Both pages are under the same domain.

What I need to do is pass all the cookies associated in the browsers page.asp request in the http request to page2.aspx.

Is this possible and if so how might I achieve it through class asp code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the HTTP "Cookie" header on your ASPX request to the value of the "Cookie" header that was received in your ASP page.

`Request.Headers('Cookie')` should have the value you want.